# Making TextView invisible after few seconds visible again

Tags: android

I'm currently exploring how to use EditText, Button and TextView. 
My program has an EditText and whenever nothing is typed in the EditText and a button is clicked, a TextView will appear for 3 seconds and become invisible again.
However, when I click on that button a second time and the EditText is still cleared, the TextView will not appear.
How can I make the TextView appear again?

```
public class NameActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

private EditText editNameText;
private TextView wrongInputTV;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_name);
    Log.i(Values.TAG, "NameActivity onCreate");

    editNameText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editNameText);
    editNameText.getText().clear();
    wrongInputTV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.wrongInputTV);
    wrongInputTV.setTextColor(Color.RED);
    ((Button) findViewById(R.id.sendNameBtn)).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            goToNextActivity();
        }
    });
}

private void goToNextActivity(){
    if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(editNameText.getText())) {;
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, DateActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(Values.NAME_KEY, editNameText.getText().toString());
        startActivity(intent);
    }else {
        wrongInputTV.setText("Please enter a valid name");
        wrongInputTV.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                wrongInputTV.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
        }, 3000);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: check how to use handler in Android

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to make textview `VISIBLE` again as you are making it `INVISIBLE` in runnable.

```
 wrongInputTV.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

So, goToNextActivity() should be written as below:-

```
private void goToNextActivity(){
    if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(editNameText.getText())) {;
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, DateActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(Values.NAME_KEY, editNameText.getText().toString());
        startActivity(intent);
    }else {
        wrongInputTV.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        wrongInputTV.setText("Please enter a valid name");
        wrongInputTV.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                wrongInputTV.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
        }, 3000);

   }
```

Note:
Initial VIEW state GONE/INVISIBLE can be set in OnCreate method.

Answer (score 0):

When working with `TextView`, it's important to understand the distinction between what you can see based on the view's *visibility* and what you can see based on the view's *text*.

The reason your original code works once but never again is that your `TextView` starts out **visible** but **empty** (you can "see" it but there's nothing to see). You then call `setText()`, making it **visible** and **non-empty** (now there's something to see). Then, after three seconds, you make it **invisible** and **non-empty** (so even though there's something to see, you can't see it).

However, nothing in your code ever changes the view's visiblity *back* to `VISIBLE` after you make it `INVISIBLE`. @lib4's answer covers (one way) how to do just that.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would handle it....

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView textView;
    EditText editText;
    Button button;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        textView = findViewById(R.id.textView);
        editText = findViewById(R.id.editText);
        button = findViewById(R.id.button);

        textView.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(editText.getText().toString().equals("") || editText.getText().toString() == null) {
                    textView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    final Handler handler = new Handler();
                    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            textView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        }
                    }, 3000);
                } else {
                    //go somewhere
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Simple XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="20dp"
    tools:context="net.pixeledstudio.hidetextview.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Type something in the text view"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/textView"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Type something"
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Submit"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```